# CRM 2011 Create data duplication log programmatically

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm trying to accomplish a duplicate detection with complex rules. The MS CRM 2011 has limitations which prevent me from setting up the standard duplicate detection rule (via UI). So I decided use .NET to solve this problem.

I'm unable to find how to write a duplicate detection rule in the .NET. But perhaps there is a way to write a plugin which would produce a duplicate detection log (result).

Is there such a possibility?

Comment: Are you looking for something like as mentioned in the below thread?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300925/how-to-identify-duplicate-records-with-a-plugin-in-dynamics-crm-2011

Comment: Found another sample from MSDN. May be helpful for you guys. Check it out. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863613.aspx